# Intended behaviour of advancedBy in Swift

Tags: swift

Is this the intended behaviour?

```
var i = 10
i.advancedBy(5, limit: 2) //15
```

& Where can I find Apple's implementation of

```
func advancedBy(n: Self.Distance, limit: Self) -> Self
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs say that this method

> Returns the result of advancing `self` by `n` positions, or until it equals `limit`.

So now let's consider your code:

```
var i = 10
i.advancedBy(5, limit: 2) //15
```

As you advance from 10, you never pass through 2, so you reach 15 without impediment. So yes, this is expected behavior.

Comment: The implementation is here: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/97d8f50af4978e54289377a0bd205e71a34529a2/stdlib/public/core/Index.swift and if you look at it you will see that the check is `if p == limit { break }`. At no time does your index equal your limit.